# Регулярное выражение для чисел с плавающей запятой

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Работаю с WPF. При вводе в текстовое поле число должно быть или целым, или десятичным, но с количеством десятичных знаков не больше одного. Целая часть не больше трех знаков. Пробовал различные варианты выражений, например

```
\d{1,3}[\.,]\d{1}|\d{1,3}
```

или

```
\d{1,3}([\.,]\d{1})?
```

Однако оба выражения позволяет вводить любое количество знаков после запятой

Comment: (?:\d*\.)?\d{3} попробуй

Comment: или (?:\d*\.)?\d{1,3}

Comment: Поробовал, то же самое, еще одно попробовал (?:\d{1,3}[\.,])\d{1} опять то же самое. Но вот странный результат, проверяю в каком-нибудь Online тестере, вроде работает. Но в программе на C# у меня метод для этой проверки с таким кодом:
          var regex = new Regex("(?:\\d{1,3}[\\.,])\\d{1}");
          var isTextAllowed = regex.IsMatch(text);
здесь не работает

Comment: А зачем вам регулярки? Почему не `TryParse` или `Binding` к `double`-свойству?

Comment: Работаю с легаси-кодом, свойство float, чтобы работать нормально с этим полем нужно проводить глубокий рефакторинг, шеф против. Поэтому мне проще в текстовом поле в событии PreviewTextInput эту проверку с регуляркой вставить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Число должно быть или целым, или десятичным, но с количеством десятичных знаков не больше одного. Целая часть не больше трех знаков.

Используйте

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\A[0-9]{1,3}(?:[.,][0-9])?\z");
```

- `\A` - начало строки (можно заменить `^`)
- `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1-3 цифры
- `(?:` - начало необязательной группы:

  - `[.,]` - точка или запятая
  - `[0-9]` - 1 цифра
- `)?` - конец необязательной группы
- `\z` - конец строки (не совсем то же самое, что `$`, так как `\z` находит только самый конец строки, после которого не может быть никаких символов)

[Демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%28%3F%3A%5B.%2C%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=1.23%0D%0A1.1%0D%0A12.2%0D%0A123.3%0D%0A.23&o=m)

Comment: Супер. Теперь все работает. Спасибо